# Trying to add a sub flyout to a Settings Charm Link

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I'm working on creating a Windows 8 application and I've created a link within the settings charm to go to a page named "Help".  On this Help page, I have a list of links that I'd like to be able to navigate to within the flyout.  I'm using the below javascript code on the help page to listen for a click event that will send users to another help category page:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var page = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/help/help.html", {
        ready: function (element, options) {
            document.getElementById("quickViewButton").addEventListener("click", gotoQuickView, false);
}
    });

    function gotoQuickView() {
        WinJS.Application.onsettings = function (e) {
            e.detail.applicationcommands = {
                "divQView": { title: "QuickView", href: "/pages/help/quickview.html" }
            };
            WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.populateSettings(e);
        };

    }

})();
```

Any ideas on what I might be missing?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: The WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.showSettings() method allows me to navigate between the sub links on my help/help.html page which works great.  However, when I go from help.html to quickview.html and try to go back to the help.html page using the back arrow button, it takes a few seconds and a few clicks in order for the method to kick in.  I'm using this code on my quickview page back button:        <button onclick="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.showSettings('help', '/pages/help/help.html')" class="win-backbutton white" aria-label="Back"></button>  Any ideas on what might be causing this delay?Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For this, [WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.showSettings()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770581.aspx) can be used.

example:

```
(function () {
  "use strict";
  var page = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/help/help.html", {
    ready: function (element, options) {
        document.getElementById("quickViewButton").addEventListener(
                "click", gotoQuickView, false);
    }
  });

  function gotoQuickView() {
    // need to ensure that settingFlyoutId in the quickview.html page 
    // is same as the first parameter below
    WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.showSettings('quickview', 
      '/pages/help/quickview.html');
  }
})();

<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout" 
     data-win-options="{settingsCommandId:'quickview'}">
```